# Get the intercept of standard error form the LinregressResult given by stats.linregres

Tags: jupyter-notebook, statistics

So when I run this line on Jupyter notebook.

```
stats.linregress(xdata, data)
```

The result is

```
LinregressResult(slope=8.762662815890456, intercept=-583.1060100267368, rvalue=0.9764595396878868, pvalue=0.0, stderr=0.0710610032681328, intercept_stderr=31.20585863555493)
```

Then if I run this code

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err,std_err_intercept = stats.linregress(xdata, data)
```

There is an error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 5)
```

But if you see there are 6 values to unpack and I need this value for my calculations could someone help, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk of the evolving API of functions in `scipy.stats`.  Old versions of `linregress` returned a tuple with length 5; they did not include the `intercept_stderr` in the result.  New versions return an object with 6 attributes.  However, for backwards compatibility, if you unpack that object, it will act like a tuple of length 5.

The simplest way to use the code is to write `result = linregress(xdata, ydata)`, and then refer to the attributes as `result.slope`, `result.intercept`, etc.  Then the standard error of the intercept is available as `result.intercept_stderr`.

If, for some reason, you must unpack the result, you can still write

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xdata, data)
```

but you lose the `intercept_stderr` part of the result.

This is explained in the Notes section of the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html).